# failed to load navbar component html file

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, angular-ui-router

I am working on angular 2 web app. I have two dev setup one on my local Macbook and other is on AWS. Basically, I have Tomcat 8 (identical version) on Macbook as well EC2 instance. My app works perfectly fine and loads components from proper directory. For example ***localhost:8080/app/component/navbar/navbar.component.html***.

But when I try to load same app on EC2 instance, my app try to load same markup from ***domainname/app/navbar/navbar.component.html***.

If you compare both URLs, I am not sure why it is skipping ***component*** directory on EC2 instance.

I looked at my ***app.module.ts*** but the code to import components looks good:

```
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
```

My whole routing is in *app.module.ts* so not sure where else to look.

I tried deleting the whole ROOT directory on EC2 and replaced with my local version.

I tried different server version like 8.5 and 9.

I tried creating fresh instance with fresh Tomcat 8 installation on EC2.

Comment: Are you using systemjs.config.js? If so, check if the file is identical on both side.

Comment: they are exactly same. i copied the whole ROOT dir of local tomcat instane to EC2 instance to avoid confusion.

Comment: Its started working but I have no idea how. I shutdown the machine went to do other work, came back restarted the machine and my app started working.

Comment: Another mystery of the cloud!! LOL!!